# Load Large Amount of Row In Cassandara / Datastax

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax

I have a table that has about 3 millions row in 1 partition key. I need to load all those data and save it as file.

Actually it is data recorded for 1 day sensor input. And what I want to build is a playback service to replay the sensor event at least in the past 3 months. So I am thinking it will be really big volume of data.

I am new in NoSql database, any approach how to achieve these goal?

Comment: what do you mean playback service - loading the data from files?

Comment: I want to load from database, store it in file, and then process it. Why do I need to store? Because I want to reuse it later, if needed.

Comment: "3 millions row in 1 partition key" - You will want to find some way to break that up.  Cassandra can't handle that many rows in a single partition.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: Can you post the table DDL? That would help, but @Aaron is right that is a very large amount of data in one partition. The partition size would easily exceed the recommended limit.